# What happens exactly when we call .then before a Promise is resolved?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

```
var promise1 = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000, 123));

setTimeout(_ => { 
  promise1.then(console.log) 
}, 500);
```

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: Do you understand what does *in general* happen when you call `.then()` on a promise?

Comment: yes simply it executes when listning promise is resolved ?

Comment: you can add a second arg callback if u want to catch promise rejections that's not the problem here !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions supplied will be queued up and fired once the promise resolves. It will also return a new promise which will be fulfilled or rejected with the return value of said functions.

If the promise is already settled, the functions will be fired on the next tick on the event loop.

In your example, the function supplied will still log it 5 seconds after the promise is made, which is 4.5 seconds after the second timeout is called.

Answer (score -2):

`then` tells the promise what to do when it finishes. You should always expect to call it before it is resolved. However, given that the devs are smart it doesn't matter if the promise resolves before then can be called.